# a table of occurances of pattern in an SQL table field

Tags: mysql, sql, string-search

I have this table

*text*

```
| txt_id | txt_content                                  |
|--------+----------------------------------------------|
|      1 | A ton of text and <<this>>                   |
|      2 | More text <<and>> that                       |
|      3 | <<Very>> much <<text>> enough for<everyone>> |
```

And this table

*tags*

```
| tag_id | tag_name |
|--------+----------|
|      1 | THIS     |
|      2 | AND      |
|      3 | VERY     |
|      4 | TEXT     |
|      5 | EVERYONE |
```

And I need a query to yield this table.

```
| txt_id | tag_id |
|--------+--------|
|      1 |      1 |
|      2 |      2 |
|      3 |      3 |
|      3 |      4 |
|      3 |      5 |
```

It would be tivial to do with python code by getting each piece of text inidividually but the *text* table has many rows (>30M) and I think it would bee to much time on the database-backend communication. Is there a way to do this kind of thing with MySQL? I would even be content with

```
| txt_id | tag_id   |
|--------+----------|
|      1 | this     |
|      2 | and      |
|      3 | Very     |
|      3 | text     |
|      3 | everyone |
```

But that I expect the last part to be easy to do within MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't necessary be particularly *fast*, but it will do what you want:

```
select t.txt_id, ta.tag_id
from text t join
     tags ta
     on t.txt_content like concat('%<', ta.tag_name, '>%');
```

Comment: You'll need wildcards.

Comment: This has also a side-effect I like of only including unique tags of each text. Out of curosity, how would you go about doing finding duplicates as well?

Comment: @fakedrake . . . I'm not sure I know what you mean.  If you want to add another column to your table that is a counter of the number of times that tags appear in a text, then that is another question.

Comment: Consider the case where the first row of `text` would be `<<this>> is a ton of text and <<this>>`. Then that entry should produce the row `(1, THIS)` twice. With the solution presented it will produce that row only once. Am I wrong?

Comment: @fakedrake . . . This will only provide one row per tag/text combination.  I could imagine a way to get a count.  Getting multiple rows is a little bit harder.